# Writing XML rows in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

My xml file is like this

```
<S_Row>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody></S_CellBody></S_Cell>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody></S_CellBody></S_Cell>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody></S_CellBody></S_Cell>
</S_Row>
```

I am handling it in python like this:

```
for i, S_Cell in enumerate(S_Row.findall('S_Cell')):
        for S_CellBody in S_Cell.getchildren():
           if i==0:
              S_CellBody.text="ABC"
```

This gives me output like this in xml file:

```
  <S_Row>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody>ABC</S_CellBody></S_Cell>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody></S_CellBody></S_Cell>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody></S_CellBody></S_Cell>
   </S_Row>
```

Now if I want to add another row and add elements in second row(1st column) like this:

```
   <S_Row>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody>ABC</S_CellBody></S_Cell>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody></S_CellBody></S_Cell>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody></S_CellBody></S_Cell>
   </S_Row>

   <S_Row>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody>DEF</S_CellBody></S_Cell>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody></S_CellBody></S_Cell>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody></S_CellBody></S_Cell>
   </S_Row>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Why not use `S_Row.find('./S_Cell/S_CellBody').text = "ABC"`? That finds the first `S_CellBody` within a `S_Row` element, no need to use `enumerate()` here.

Comment: It is otherwise unclear with how you want to add the extra row. Should it be a copy of the previous row? Should it always have the same 3-cell structure?

Comment: Because there were more elements I am writing in other rows so want to keep records of rows, also I am modifying the full file first then writing it so it doesn't save what I have already written in it.

Comment: Yes, extra rows should always have 3-cell structure

Comment: @Inbar: I am modfying the XML file in Python using etree, in modification I am wrting more rows

Answer (score 0):

Considering a as XMLstring

```
import cElementTree    
a1=cElementTree.fromstring(a)
strlst=['ABC','DEF','GHI']
for i,row in enumerate(a1.findall('S_Row')):    
    cb = row.getchildren()[0].getchildren()[0]
    cb.text = strlst[i+1]         
cElementTree.tostring(a1)
```